# What do you call an L1 regularization term involving a matrix vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, regularization

Often times I have difficulties finding certain things when I do not use the correct terminology. Or there are many different terms for the same thing.
I would like to know what you would call the following optimization problem, so I have an idea what to look for:

$
\begin{align}
\min\limits_{x} ||Ax-b||^2_2 + \lambda \mathcal{R}(x)
\end{align}
$

where the regularizer is of the form

$
\mathcal{R}(x) = ||Dx||_1
$

What if $D$ is just a positive diagonal matrix? Would it be called differently?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Weighted $L_1$ regularization?

Comment: Isn't it equivalent to minimising $\|Bx - b\|_2^2$ with $B=AD^{-1}$ with standard $L^1$ regularisation? (Obviously supposing that you want to use an invertible $D$, which, with the standard meaning given to positive, is the case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by positive you mean strictly positive, so that all the diagonal elements are $>0$, then $D$ is invertible and your problem is equivalent to
$$\min_{y}\|By-b\|^2_2+\lambda\|y\|_1\,,$$
where $B = AD^{-1}$ and you're using the standard $L^1$-regularisation.

If you're interested in the $x^\star$ achieving the minimum in your original problem, it is simply given by
$$x^\star = D^{-1}y^\star\,,$$
where $y^\star$ achieves the minimum in the standard-regularised problem.

**EDIT**

Note that $D$ does not even need to be diagonal or positive defined, just invertible, in order to go back to the original $L^1$-regularisation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Tried it out and works like a charm. Out of curiosity, how would one proceed if the operator is not invertible?